# Font is not being loaded on IE11 on Html Page when meta tag set to 'content="IE=7"'

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, font-face

On this HTML page, the font 'Patua one' is `not` getting loaded for the text 'TESTING Page Tools' when this `meta` tag set to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>` only on `IE 11`, but, it's working on rest of versions of `IE`. However, this 'Patua one' font is getting loaded on `IE 11`, lower versions of IE and rest of the browsers **when** i set this `meta` tag to `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>`.

Anyway, I need to use `content=IE=7`only on the `meta` tag as to my requirement. On this situation, this font 'Patua one' is not getting loaded on `IE 11` **only** and this works rest of the versions of IE and other browsers as well (firefox, chrome etc). If I change this `meta` tag's attribute to `content=IE=edge`, then, it is getting loaded in all the versions of IE and other browsers as well. However, as per the deal, i **should not change** the `meta` tag's attribute from `content=IE=7`to `content=IE=edge`

My Aim[that i am expecting]: I need this 'Patua One' font should get loaded `even` when `meta` tag's attribute set to `'IE=7'`.

I need someone's help on this. Please.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
<style>
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Patua One';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Patua One'), local('PatuaOne-Regular'), url('http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/patuaone/v5/yAXhog6uK3bd3OwBILv_SD8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff') format('woff');
}

.channelname h2 {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    font: 26px 'Patua One',Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif !important;
    letter-spacing: 0.2px;
    padding-left: 0.5em !important;
    color: blue;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="cs" class="channelname">
<h2>TESTING Page Tools</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add a *HTML conditional statement* to the `<head>` tag on the start of the code:

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE 11]> -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Or if it doesn't work, try this:

```
<!--[if IE 11]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE 11]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7"/>
<![endif]-->
```

Hope it works.

Comment: And if you have any issue with IE 11 on understand the html conditions, try this: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">`